# google compute enging postfix relay through gmail

Tags: postfix, smtp, google-compute-engine

I would like to send directly through gmail, since we have google apps and use gmail as our domain email.

I would like to get rid of sendgrid so I can possibly not be marked as spam.

I found this https://rtcamp.com/tutorials/linux/ubuntu-postfix-gmail-smtp/ which shows how to setup postfix to use gmail smtp, but shows that it uses port 587, and I know that my current setup with sendgrid uses port 2525.

Is it possible to push like this through gmail?

Comment: You can use whatever port you want. Just do it and ask if any problems arise.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in this [article](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/) you can send emails using your Google Compute Engine instance through ports 587, 465 using Google Apps.

```
To send email through ports 587 or 465, you can use your Google Apps domain if you have one.
```

There is a sending limit when relaying through Gmail account. You can go through this [link](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2956491?hl=en) for more information on the sending limits.

I hope that helps.

Comment: huh.. Odd that when I google'd like crazy, I didn't get that page, but always got the google sendgrid page on how to set it up.

Comment: And that link doesn't really give you the example of how to do it, or what settings to use.

Comment: This link (https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/using-sendgrid) has the steps to configure Postfix with sendgrind on GCE. To configure SMTP relay service for Postfix using Gmail you can follow the steps on this link (https://support.google.com/a/answer/2956491?hl=en).

Comment: If my answer was useful can you go ahead and accept it as an answer.

Answer (score -1):

Here is what I followed [Configure Postfix to Use Gmail SMTP](https://rtcamp.com/tutorials/linux/ubuntu-postfix-gmail-smtp/)

This worked and I currently am testing it with my own personal gmail account.

took about 5 minutes to setup.

if you have problems, make sure you look below at the comments on that page.